# AccessViolationException in System.Web

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, crash

I have a web server running IIS 10 and a .NET Framework 4.8 MVC website. I am occassionally (every few hours or so) seeing crashes leading to entries in the event viewer saying "A process serving application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '5724'. The data field contains the error number." (the error number was 8007006D).

After some investigation into a crash dump (something I'm no expert on so may have missed many ways to get more info) I found the following information. The exception that caused the crash was a System.AccessViolationException and I've added the full stack trace to the end of this post but the top of the stack trace was System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdReadEntityBody and looking at that it seems to be a method that calls into the webengine4.dll .

The main thing I am seeking assistance on is how to stop this error happening. Because the error is in Microsoft code it looks like this is a problem with the IIS code so I am not sure what I can do to help deal with this.

One change I have made to try to resolve this is a suggestion I found which was to set the "Enable 32-bit applications" option to true. This seems to have reduced the number of access violation exceptions that happens but the above is one example of one that has happened since.

I have seen some posts that suggest building all my .net code against platform x86 rather than "Any" might help but before I make this change to our production servers (we don't seem to be having this problem on our test/staging servers) I'd like to understand a) if it is likely to work and b) why this or the Enable 32-bit applications is necessary. I'm also very confused by why it is only crashing occasionally - I assume that it is something like most of the time it is reading/writing to valid memory and for some reason very rarely its pointers are wrong/invalid but this isn't an area I know much about...

Stack Trace:

00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdReadEntityBody+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadEntityCoreSync+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadEntityBody+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Item+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Item+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Mvc.AjaxRequestExtensions.IsAjaxRequest+0x0

[Our code]

00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper+0x0
00000000 00000000 System_Web_ni!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification+0x0

Edit: This is a cross-post from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/736607/accessviolationexception-in-systemweb.html

Comment: I have replied the question posted on Q&A and I'll continue discuss with you there.